# pause the game when enter foreground, after restart

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

I developed a game using Cocos2d-x. In playscene, there is a pause button for pausing the game. I used the following code to pause the particular scene.

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->pause();
```

My question is when user press pause button the game is paused, then he press end button in keypad it gone to pause. But when he restart the game its resumed. I don't want to resume, until when user press resume button in playscene.

I know in `appdelegate.cpp` I used resume function when enter foreground, but i am not getting any solutions with this?

Answer (score 0):

Cocos automatically resumes the scenes when your game is brought to foreground. The simplest solution in your case would be to set a global flag, i.e. `manualPause`, check it in `applicationWillEnterForeground` and act accordingly.